# TortoiseSVN auto detecting existed files and checkout from svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm working on git and svn.

Is there a way to auto detect the folders/files, which are already existed(one of the folder cloned from git) by svn and checkout at same time?

What I do is：

1. Clone my project from Git.
2. Make svn checkout those folders/files under the folder "sass".

I know there is a way to checkout manually. But if there are a lot, it may be a trouble.

Comment: Could you please rephrase or reword your question? I don't really get what you mean by "auto detect".

Comment: @bahrep I want the system detect the files I already have. For example: I have 3 files  on remote server, but in my file there are only two files. And I want the system knows that what files I already have and helps me checkout automatically.